# How does one evaluate the multiplication $f(2)\cdot f(3)\cdot f(4)\cdots f(15)$ by formulating?

Tags: functions, products

Suppose

$$f : \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$f(x) = 1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$

How does one evaluate the multiplication $\prod_{i=2}^{15} f(i)=f(2)\cdot f(3)\cdot f(4)\cdots f(15)$?

Here I have to see the trick that directly yields the calculation.

How come that we write this using *$\Pi$ (product) notation*? I'll be glad to hear your dear thoughts.

Comment: Have you looked carefully at the product of the first few terms?  I think if you use a bit of algebra, you'll see that there is some cancellation between numerators and denominators of adjacent terms.

Comment: @hardmath That's absolutely true. I also have looked carefully at the product of first few terms, no doubt.

Comment: It would also depend on how you write those terms. If you just write $\left(1 - \frac1{2^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac1{3^2}\right)\left(1 - \frac1{4^2}\right)\cdots$ then I don't think you will see a useful pattern.

Comment: I have got $$\frac{8}{15}$$ with my TI calculator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $f(x) =  \frac{x^2-1}{x^2} =  \frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x^2}$
 
and take product of $f(2),f(3),...,f(n)$

Look:
$$
\frac{(1)(3)}{2^2} \cdot \frac{(2)(4)}{3^2} \cdot \frac{(3)(5)}{4^2} \cdot ... \frac{(n-3)(n-1)}{(n-2)^2} \cdot \frac{(n-2)n}{(n-1)^2} \cdot \frac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{n+1}{n} $$
 and take this for your task

Comment: That does not really help.

Comment: @Enzo Perhaps you should try harder to understand it. It is the same hint I would have given; I don't think there is an easier way.

Comment: Write as I said and look what will happen

Comment: @Enzo I'll go out on a limb and say that there is *no* easier way.

Comment: $$\biggr (\frac{(2-1)(2+1)}{2^2} \biggr ) \biggr ( \frac{(3-1)(3+1)}{3^2} \biggr )$$ No such term cancels out here.

Comment: @Enzo Remember $$\prod\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x^2}=\frac{\prod(x-1)\cdot\prod(x+1)}{\prod x\cdot\prod x}$$You might want to use the factorial notation to work out the answer.

Comment: @Enzo Write out a few more terms, but do the additions and subtractions. The cancelations will appear before your eyes like magic.

Answer (score 2):

> It  is also convenient  to  use the *[factorial notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)* $n!=1\cdot2\cdots n$. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\prod_{i=2}^{15}f(i)}&=\prod_{i=2}^{15}\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)\\
> &=\prod_{i=2}^{15}\frac{i^2-1}{i^2}\\
> &=\prod_{i=2}^{15}\frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i^2}\\
> &=\frac{14!\cdot 16!/2}{\left(15!\right)^2}\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{8}{15}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $\prod_{i=2}^{15}(i-1)=1\cdot 2\cdots 14=14!$ and $\prod_{i=2}^{15}(i+1)=3\cdot4\cdots 16=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 16!$.
- In (2) we see that $14!/15!=1/15$ and $16!/15!=16$.